# How to stop network manager changing my gateway?

Tags: networking, dhcp, routing

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04

Problem:

I want to connect to my VPN at work from home. Whenever I connect to my wireless, my route is set up to the work route. The home gateway is supposed to be 192.168.1.254 and manually setting the default gateway to be this works. But when I try and connect to the VPN using the applet, or when I disconnect and reconnect the wireless, the default gateway is set back to the work one making working from home much more difficult than it should be.

Network interfaces are apparently configured with dhcp but the routing appears not to be because when I do `sudo dhclient` the default gateway is unset and `route -n` yields,

```
route -n
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

and there's just a network unreachable error.

Upon connecting and disconnecting the wireless interface through the gui, (clicking on the applet) suddenly we get the output from route -n shown below. I've ack-grepped the entirety of /etc for 192.168.192.9 to no avail.

Clearly something in Ubuntu has been configured to set up the route wrongly.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use      Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.9   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0     wlan0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.192.9   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlan0
```